# Renomear arquivos em python utilizando lista em Excel

Tags: python

estou tentando realizar a seguinte função:
Renomear uma lista de arquivos de acordo com a data de modificação deles, sendo do mais antigo para o mais novo.
O nome dos arquivos eu tenho em uma lista em Excel e a intenção é renomear o arquivo mais antigo com a 1ª linha do excel, segundo arquivo mais antigo com a 2ª linha do Excel. O código que tenho hoje renomeia apenas um arquivo aleatório com a 1ª linha e depois da erro:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
#lista dos links
urls = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/u0000008/Documents/Excel/Controle de Janelas - Comissões - 2a Janela.xlsm', sheet_name ='Respostas',)

path = r'C:\Users\u0000008\Downloads'
files = os.listdir(path)
mod_time = os.path.getmtime(r'C:\Users\u0000008\Downloads')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(mod_time))
lista_nomes =[] 
for Nome, file in enumerate(files):
    lista_nomes =[] 
    for Nome in urls ['Digite e selecione o nome ou o código de seu escritório abaixo:']:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(Nome), '.pdf'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Não considerei seu exemplo de código para a resposta.
Sugiro revisar a estrutura do código.

Me atendo ao problema definido como:

> Renomear uma lista de arquivos de acordo com a data de modificação
> deles, sendo do mais antigo para o mais novo. O nome dos arquivos eu
> tenho em uma lista em Excel e a intenção é renomear o arquivo mais
> antigo com a 1ª linha do excel, segundo arquivo mais antigo com a 2ª
> linha do Excel.

Minha sugestão de solução é como abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = "D:\\Downloads\\teste\\"
f = pd.read_excel("D:\\Desktop\\nomes_arquivos.xlsx")

# conteúdo do arquivo excel:
print(f)

       0
0  Arq01
1  Arq02
2  Arq03
3  Arq04
4  Arq05

# conteudo do diretório com os arquivos:
for name in os.listdir(folder):
    print(name)

file01.txt
file02.txt
file04.txt
file05.txt
file10.txt

# gero uma lista com o par: (nome_arquivo, mtime)
L = [tuple([item, os.path.getmtime(folder + item)]) for item in os.listdir(folder)]

# ordeno a lista utilizando o mtime como chave
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])

# reduzo a lista apenas aos nomes dos arquivos, na ordem acima
L = [item[0] for item in L]

# gero uma lista com os nomes dos arquivos
nomes = list(f[0])

# utilizo zip() para construir o rename

# observação importante: os arquivos renomeados estarão no diretório de origem, e não no diretório do arquivo com a lista de nomes

for velho, novo in zip(L, nomes):
    os.rename(os.path.join(folder, velho), os.path.join(folder, ''.join([novo, '.pdf'])))
```

Sugiro ler [esse artigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) sobre como elaborar uma boa pergunta.